# Working with Java - Print four iterations per 9 character wide line

Tags: java, loops

```java
// Write a program that uses a while loop to detect and print multiples of 13 or 17, but not both. Use the exclusive or operator as on page 93. 
// The program should start examining integers at 200, and examine successively larger integers until 16 multiples have been detected. 
// Correct multiples should be printed right aligned in fields that are 9 characters wide, but with only four multiples per line. 
// The total of all correct multiples should be reported after all 16 multiples have been printed.

package Programs5;

public class Program51 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int main = 200, x = 0, y = 13, z = 17;
        while(x < 16) {
            main += 1;
            if(main % y == 0 ^ main % z == 0) {
                x += 1;
                System.out.print(main + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the program, the logic works and prints each multiple properly. However I need to print four iterations per line. For example:

`x x x x`

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I am assuming I need a loop of sorts from my little experience in python but I am just lost at this point.

Comment: Keep track of your prints with some variable, say: `numPrints`. Increment it every time you call `System.out.print()`. The check if `numPrints` is divisible by 4 (you're already using this operation). If it is, print a newline.

Comment: what do you mean by increment it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to align your fields in nine character wide columns (I would use `printf`, and simply add a line break when the `count` is a multiple of four). I would start by saving the results of the modulo operations in local variables. Also, you need to keep a running total. Something like,

```
int count = 0, total = 0, start = 200;
for (; count < 16; start++) {
    boolean mod13 = start % 13 == 0, mod17 = start % 17 == 0;
    if (mod13 ^ mod17) {
        if (count > 0) {
            if (count % 4 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        total += start;
        System.out.printf("% 9d", start);
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("%nTotal = %d%n", total);
```

Outputs

```
      204       208       234       238
      247       255       260       272
      273       286       289       299
      306       312       323       325
Total = 4331
```

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling with Java.